# Why am I getting duplicate values written to the DB while fetching data with async.parallel & async.forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to build a web scraper with node, currently I need to fetch transaction history data for each product. I am using the node-postgres and async libraries.

This is my database schema:

```
id [PK](bigint)   |   data (json[])
------------------------------------
```

If I run my code, it makes a correct, unique entry for every ID. The data however, is sometimes duplicated for multiple products, like that:

```
123   |   {date: 2018-11-01, number: 2}
345   |   {date: 2018-11-03, number: 5}
567   |   {date: 2018-11-03, number: 5}
789   |   {date: 2018-11-03, number: 5}
912   |   {date: 2018-11-04, number: 24}
---------------------------------------
```

So the products 345, 567 and 789 share the same data, but it should be different. This is my code:

```
var getTx = async function(product, callback){
  getTransactionsParallel(product.id, daysOfHistory)
  .then(function(transactions) {
    client.query('INSERT INTO tx (id, data) VALUES ($1, $2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;', [product.id, transactions], (err, res) => {
      if(!err){
        logger.info('|| Inserted TX into DB ' + product.id);
        callback();
      } else {
        logger.error('|| Error while inserting product ' + product.id)
        callback();
      }
    })
  })
}

client.query("select * from products", (err, res) => {
  if(!err){
    products = res.rows;
  } else {
    logger.error(err.stack)
  }

  _.each(products, function(product) {
    work.push(function(callback){
      getTx(product, callback)
    })
  })

  async.parallelLimit(work, 10, function(){
    logger.info(' || Finished. || ');
  })
})
```

And those are the functions for getting the data itself:

```
const getTransactionPage = async function(offset, id, daysOfHistory, callback ){
  try {
      await rp({ uri: url, forever: true, agent: false })
      .then(($) => {
        body = $.replace('result(', '');
        body = body.replace(');', '');
        let data;

        if(data = JSON.parse(body)){
          let transactions = data.records;
          _.each(transactions, function(transaction){
            // push to array
          });
        }
      })
      callback();
  }
};

const getTransactionsParallel = function(id, daysOfHistory){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // async request to fetch maxpages (async function [...] await rp(url) [...])
    getMaxPages(id, function(maxPages){
      let pages = Array.from({length: maxPages}, (v, k) => k+1);

      async.forEach(pages, function(page, callback){
        getTransactionPage(page, id, daysOfHistory, callback)
      }, function done(err, res){
        resolve(dataArray)
      });
    })
  })
}
```

So, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Do not mix promises with the callback-style `async.js` library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, that did not fix it. I tried adding a callback to `getTransactionsParallel` but it still yields the same result.